# how to make this jquery request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do an ajax request. Code in the controller:

```
def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def show
end

def create
@post = Post.new(post_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

jquery ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.submit').on('click', function(event){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/posts',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        // data: {param1: 'value1'},
        data: {name: 'value1', comment: 'value2'}
    })
})
```

});

Data is getting stored except it is not happening through ajax and I am getting an error `"undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass"` in show page

edit 1:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name %><br>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= f.label :comment %><br>
<%= f.text_field :comment %>
    <%= f.submit class: 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```

edit 2:
route file:

```
 root 'posts#index'
  resources :posts
```

show.html.erb

```
  Name: <%= @post.name %>
  Comment: <%= @post.comment %>
```

The controller has been scaffolded. 
        `format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }` came with scaffold.

after adding your code for def show, my show page works. But the post is not happening through ajax.

Comment: if data is getting stored but not through ajax you are just posting the form surely? what does your form look like? you should do on('submit') and return false if you want to use ajax `$('#formId').on('submit', function(){ $.ajax({ /* ajax code */ }); return false; });`

Comment: added my form. my submit button has a class.

Comment: You are not using the JSON output of your action. Which raises the question: what exactly are you trying to achieve by using AJAX?

Comment: How do I output the JSON from the action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @posts = Post.all
   end

   def new
      @post = Post.new
   end

   def create
      @post = Post.new post_params

      respond_to do |format|
         if @post.save #-> this is your code, I haven't changed it much
            format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created }
         else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
   end

   private

   def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:name, :comment)
   end
end
```

And the front-end:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("submit", "#new_post", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      url: '/posts',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {post: $(this).serialize()},
      success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
      },
      error: function(data) { 
          alert(data);
      }   
   });
});

#app/views/posts/show.html.erb
Name <%= @post.name %>
Comment <%= @post.comment %>
```

There are several issues with your implementation:

---

***1. Submit***

Your first problem is you're binding requests to the *submit button*.

Although this will appear to work, the true way to do it is to bind to the *submit event*: `$.on("submit"`.

This means you have to bind to the *form*, from which you'll be able to collate the inputted data using the [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function.

-

***2. Data***

Secondly, you're setting your own data.

Whilst not a problem in itself (the syntax is correct), it does nothing for your application. You're basically sending `{name: 'value1', comment: 'value2'}` every single time.

You'll be *much* better setting the data using the data from the form. I've done this in my example using: `{post: $(this).serialize()}`, which should set the parameters as follows:

```
"post":
   {
     "name": [[name input]],
     "comment": [[comment input]]
   }
```

-

***3. Ajax***

Finally, are you *sure* you want to do this with Ajax?

Ajax stands for **A**synchronous **J**avascript **a**nd **X**ML - it means you can send requests outside the "normal" scope for HTTP.

Although you're well within your liberty to do this, I don't see the benefits of it in this case?

---

## UJS

A better way to handle this functionality is to use the [Rails UJS (unobtrusive javascript) driver](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs).

This basically binds preformatted JS to your HTML elements depending on a series of `data` attributes you add:

```
#app/views/posts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @post, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :comment %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :comment %>
  <%= f.submit class: 'submit' %>
<% end %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:success", "#new_post", function(data, status, xhr){
   // success request
});
```

You can see more about the [custom Rails UJS events](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) here.

---

## Comments

> But the post is not happening through ajax.

This will be caused by you not sending the correct data through your system.

I've addressed this in my first set of code -- you'll be best biding the JS function to the `form#submit` event and passing the serialized data through your ajax.

Of course, you don't have to use Ajax in this case.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Since I was trying to use submit button instead of submit event. now it recognises but I am getting an error of internal server error 500 in console. The error alert shows `The page at localhost says [object Object]`.

Comment: You'll have to use a cheeky bit of JSON parsing -- `alert( JSON.stringify(data))`

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you. It took me a while to get a hang of what you explained then used it for reference and I got it now.Your code helped me a lot thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If your submit button looks like this:

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit my form" />
```

(Make sure `class="submit"` is part of it, as that is how you select it in your jQuery call)

Try:

```
$(function(){
  $('.submit').on('click', function(event){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/posts',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {name: 'value1', comment: 'value2'}
    });
    return false;
  });
})
```

Notice the `return false;` at the end that prevents the normal submission to kill the AJAX request.

The error you're getting on your show page seems unrelated to this and is likely caused by the contents of `views/posts/show.erb` . You should open a new question about that.

**UPDATE**: I'll comment on the show action anyway. It looks incorrect (Even though I haven't seen your show page):

```
format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
```

You can already access @post. I don't know what `location: @post` is supposed to do, are you using that in your view?

If I look in your JavaScript, you're not doing anything with the JSON output on the AJAX request.

Also, in the controller, try:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

If that doesn't work, edit your question and give us your show view and your routes file.

Comment: This is how my submit button looks. it has a class of submit which I use for my jquery. `<%= f.submit class: 'submit' %>`

Comment: Pelle, my problem is data is getting stored and I can see it on the index page too.  However it is not showing on my show page. I get this error that I mentioned before. Btw how do you tell that it is getting stored via ajax? even when I comment out the posts.js, I can still create posts and retrieve them on the index. meaning ajax is not working. .yes! added return false, still it is not working.

Comment: In your case: AJAX will not make your browser redirect. Actually, you won't see a thing if you click that button. You can see if an XHR is done in your browser's developer tools. (cmd-opt-i in chrome or safari on mac). If it gets redirected, it's not an AJAX request. (Which means you either didn't `return false`, or your selector doesn't find the submit button element.)

Comment: So, what exactly does happen when you click the button after adding `return false`?

Comment: Two things that was not making it work- 1) I was trying to use submit button instead of submit event. 2) I had my ajax code in a new file called posts.js under javascript. But when I moved it to application.js it works! I tried with both as prevent default as mentioned by Rich and return false they both work but still I am getting an alert error -`The page at localhost says [object Object]` and `error 500`.

Comment: Thanks Pelle for your help.